# using linq2sql, what if my db model doesn't have any relationships mapped? ramifications?

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

My database doesn't have any FK mapped in the tables, only PK indexes.

If I use linq2sql, what are the ramifications of this db design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate your model you will get a set of free standing tables.

You do not get all of the join functionality out of the box.

If you are only going to use Linq2sql to read data from and write data to one table at a time, you do not need the foreign keys.

Comment: if I setup the foreign keys, can I tell it to ignore the relations?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can map everything in your app.. but sql server will naturally optimise indexes with FK relations. You will be loosing a lot of in-built performance gains by not having some relationships in the db.